# mod_register not working in ejabberd server (In-band Registration) using asmack

Tags: ejabberd

I have ejabberd server running I can check this by browsing to `domain.com:5280/admin` - it is running well but when I want to register users from android client asmack it says `403 error`. I have changed access rules (deny to allow) but the same problem persists. Then i found that I have to change `<code>mod_register[{access,register}]</code>` to `<code>mod_register[{access_from,register}]</code>`but since doing that the server is unable to start, I've reverted all the settings to check if the problem persists with this line but nothing happened.

I checked the error log file it says case cause `<code>mod_register[{access_from,register}]</code>` and now I am unable to even re-install ejabberd because it says `failed` while starting.

Please help me on this i am new to ejabberd.

Comment: I found the problem. Ejabberd processes are still running even after uninstalling. So, I just killed them and also killed beam process of erlang. now working fine. The ejabberd process was using resources because of this new ejabberd not able to access them. So, the result was failed to start.

Answer (score 1):

Start installing a fresh copy of Ejabberd.

To allow inband registration modify ejabberd.cfg file. Check this configuration:

ACCESS RULE:

{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.

Under mod_register:

{mod_register, [{acces, register}]}.

i commented out {ip_access, [{allow, "127.0.0.0/8}, {deny, "0.0.0.0/0"}} to allow clients in other server machine to register accounts.

that solved my problem.